# Input shape incompatible ResNet

Tags: python, machine-learning, resnet

I tried using my model to predict/classify, but it said:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer “sequential_2” is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 45, 45, 3), found shape=(None, 45, 3)
```

even though when I took the shape of the input, it was (45,45,3) not (None,45,3)

This is my code:

```
data=list(uploaded.keys())

image=cv2.imread(data[0])

img_reverted=cv2.bitwise_not(image)

print(np.shape(preprocess_input(img_reverted)))

preds = model.predict(preprocess_input(img_reverted))

print(‘Predicted:’, decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
```

Comment: can you also add output of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was expecting a tensor of 4 dimensions, but I only gave one sample, so it was 3 dimensions.